Power supply issue with virtual ground for the INA333 and AD630 amplifier
I implemented a circuit with the INA333 amplifier to read a sensor, then the amplifier sends the signal to the AD630, which plays the role of a lock in amplifier, as in the diagram I sent.

I made a symmetrical source to power the IC AD630 with +/- 12V, using the IC 741 to generate a virtual ground. As the INA333 is powered by 3.3V, I placed an LM317 to regulate the voltage to the correct value for the INA CI, like the other diagram.

Can I use the virtual ground as a common ground for the entire circuit? If not, how should I do it?
For now I am using the virtual ground provided by circuit 741

In the upper schematic you have V2 and V3 already providing a ground, why you want to make it with the 741? The output of 741 is definitely missing some capacitor. And you create -7V (+5V? above -12V) with U2 - didn't you want to relate it to ground instead of -12 V? And is the output of 741 is strong enough to provide all currents in- and output, that can occur?

@BitLauncher I'm sorry, maybe I didn't explain it right. As my native language is not English, I may have been confused. In the first circuit I have the INA333, needing 3.3V to work, together with the AD630, which needs a voltage source of +/- 12V. To solve this problem I made the circuit in the second figure, using the 741 to supply the voltage of +/- 12V, with the virtual ground, together with a voltage regulator to supply 3.3V to the INA333.

@BitLauncher My question would be whether I can use the virtual ground, generated by the 741, for a common ground for the entire circuit. Would this be possible? Thank you very much.

Do you really have a single 24V battery source, or (2) 12V Cells, or something other?

@ChrisKnudsen I have a single 24V DC source

You can use the virtual ground - if INA333 never uses more than 4 mA power supply current. And U2 RV1 connects to virtual ground instead -12V.
But there some question marks that arise with your circuit and explanations, whether it will work finally.
The virtual ground has to be able to source and sink the currents that happen - the 741 is able to drive at least 10 mA. With 12 V it makes only 120 mW, below 500 mW total power. But also in the occurring frequencies of its changes? 741 is slow - decoupling capacitors could help --> a)
a) But it is always a best practice to use decoupling capacitors, especially that the 741 is a very old and quite slow opamp.
So I would put ceramic capacitors of ca. 100 to 470 nF between +12/-12V and 2 same values between 0V and +12V and -12V (perhaps even a resistor of e. g. 100 Ohm between opamp output and these 2 capacitors?).
b) You write 3.3 V for INA333 but "ADJ 5V", that confuses me.
c) Also the U2 LM317 is related to -12 V! I assume it should relate to (virtual) ground 0V.
d) then the LM317 is also an old fashioned voltage regulator, that needs for operation already around 6 mA (1.25V / 220 Ohm), what flow into the virtual ground - that is ok. But how much is the supply current of INA333 during operation? Less than 4 mA to fullfill the min. 10 mA of the 741 output? Nowadays voltage regulator fixed to 3.3 V with far less bias current can be bought.
e) The INA333 (around 99 EUR) and the AD630 (around 33 EUR) are very high end electronics. So using cheap and old fashioned 741 and LM317 is contradictory - better parts are available. Are these expensive chips (INA333/AD630) needed? No cheaper, less precise would do?
f) Because the expensive ICs seem to be used to measure a noisy signal very precisely (25uV offset) - INA333 amplifies the signal with factor 5 (R1 = 25 kOhm). But what does the AD630 wiring is not very readable. Can you explain which configuration you use via datasheet or explain more?
g) INA333 has a very low offset of 25 uV, if this is really needed, then some more considerations are important:

voltage drop over ground connections etc., e. g. star shaped ground connections
all the connections and metal changes between sensor and circuit could be influenced by Seebeck effect - e. g. 5 °C difference between copper and stainless steal creates already 25 uV (german, "Abbildung 12")

h) AD630 helps with very noisy sensor signals, if that is true here, then the circuit should also filter out these noise signals. Otherwise they could influence the virtual ground negatively etc. As mentionned above, use decoupling capacitors and other noise reducing technologies. Perhaps even considerations of EMI are needed.
